Can I create a hardware device with USB 2.0 interface, but with USB-C connector?
I would like to create a hardware device that uses a MCU chip with a USB 2.0 interface. But I would like to use an USB-C connector on this device to be able to use the 3 Amp from the USB-C port and eventually more power if the port supports the PD (Power Delivery) feature.
Is that possible/allowed?

Yes, this is possible.
The USB 2.0 protocol works with all USB connectors, including the USB C connector.
Without any special negotiation, your device will be able draw 0.5A of current at 5V. That's the official USB 2.0 limit. Most power supplies will not care and happily deliver up to 2A o of current.
If more than 2A or more than 5V is needed,USB Power Delivery can be used. It requires active negotiation between the device and the power supply. To implement it, either an additional USB PD chip or a microcontroller including a USB PD peripheral (like many MCUs of the STM32 G family) is required.
USB PD relies on the CC lines that are only present in USB C connector.

And how do I know how much power my device can draw?
When connecting to a USB-C the CC lines are used to negotiate the power. So my device can know how much.
But how do I know if my device is connected to USB 2.0 (0.5A 5V) or USB 3.0 (5V 0.9A)? And are there other possibilities?

I‘m not sure how you can distinguish between USB 2.0 and 3.0. You would probably need to start with 0.5A and observe the requests over the data lines. But in practice, 99% of power sources will deliver 1A. Do it shouldn‘t be a real issue.
